# CRM 2011 - Rollback mechanism for triggering a plugin within another plugin

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I have a question regarding the rollback mechanism in CRM 2011. I know that a synchronous plugin will rollback any changes it has performed if an error is thrown. But what if this plugin triggers another plugin during it's execution.

Consider the following plugins:

1. Plugin A: Triggers on pre-UPDATE of Task entity
2. Plugin B: Triggers on pre-UPDATE of Case(incident) entity

Scenario would be like this:

1. I update a case and Plugin B get's triggered.
2. Fields in the case are modified
3. One of the Tasks associated with the case is also updated with some information.

   - Plugin A is triggered
   - Fields related to the task are modified
4. Some other operations on the case record
5. Plugin B throws exception

My question is, would the operations performed in Plugin A get rolled back as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as the plugins are registered in the transaction (before or after, but still in), everything will get rolled back.  If a plugin is registered for the `Pre-Validation` stage, it will not get rolled back.

This also assumes that you're retrieving the `IOrganziationService` from the `PluginContext` as well.

This is what happens on the server:

1. A request to update an entity comes in, are we currently in a transaction via the context?  If not create a new Database Transaction and store it in the Plugin Context.
2. Request is made to update a different entity, transaction is passed to the new plugin's context, and step 1 is repeated for new plugin execution.